# Image recognised in Android Studio but invisible on Phone

Tags: android, image, android-icons

My Images are being recognised like so (Look at the left):

[image]

However when I run the app on my phone the images just become invisible.

This just happened all of a sudden, I don't believe I changed anything other than copied other images into the folder, it seems like there is no consistency.

Also, I tried moving the icon images into the `mipmap` folders, specifically `mdpi`.

Still no luck. (So drawables and mipmap are broken?)

Any ideas?

Comment: Please be more specific. They become invisible in your navigation drawer? The toolbar? Maybe a screenshot of (not) them? Like this it's a stab in the dark

Comment: It's invisible in the navigation drawer. Basically nothing exists where the image is supposed to be ... (invisible)

Comment: Could it be that they are just the same color (close to the same color) as the background? Since they seem quite white-ish. Do you see them when clicking on them?

Comment: That's not the issue unfortunately. As I said, it was working fine before... and I didn't go near that code. I tried cleaning the project... no luck.

Comment: It should be in `drawable` not `mipmap` and you said you placed them in `mdpi`, if your phone is a higher dpi then you may not get proper results (stretched/blurry), seeing as the images are quite light it could be a possible issue.

Comment: I tried `drawable` originally. I only moved to `mipmap` because I thought `drawable` may have been the issue. You can see in screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you changed the theme recently?

If you have a white navigation bar but are using a `dark` theme, then the icons will show up white, regardless of the color you set them to.

So they are still there, but just the same color as the background.

Try changing the theme to a `light` theme.

If this works, but the rest of the app such as the `Toolbar` is not the correct color/theme, you can always override the theme for the `Toolbar`:

```
app:theme="@style/Dark.Overlay"
```